# Почему во вложенном компоненте не обновляются значения?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Есть компонент `FormComponent`:

```
export class FormComponent extends React.Component<any>{

    private _firstName :string;
    private _lastName :string;

    constructor(props :any){
        super(props);
        this._firstName = this.props.firstName;
        this._lastName = this.props.lastName;
    }

    get firstName(): string {
        return this._firstName;
    }

    set firstName(value: string) {
        this._firstName = value;
        this.setState({firstName: this.firstName});
    }

    get lastName(): string {
        return this._lastName;
    }

    set lastName(value: string) {
        this._lastName = value;
        this.setState({lastName: this.lastName});
    }

    public render() {
        return <div>
                <form action="">
                    <div>
                        <label>First name:</label><br/>
                        <InputComponent value={this.firstName}/>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>Last name:</label><br/>
                        <InputComponent value={this.lastName}/>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
               </div>;
    }
}
```

У `FormComponent` есть вложенные компоненты `InputComponent`:

```
export class InputComponent extends React.Component<any>{

    private _value :string;

    constructor(props :any){
        super(props);
        this._value = this.props.value;
    }

    get value(): string {
        return this._value;
    }

    set value(value: string) {
        this._value = value;
        this.setState({value: this.value});
    };

    public render() {
        return <div className="form__input-box">
                <div className="form__input-wrapper">
                    <input value={this.value} />
                </div>
               </div>;
    }

}
```

Все это инициализируется так:

```
let form :any = ReactDOM.render(
     <FormComponent firstName="123" />, document.getElementById('reactBlock')
);

setTimeout(() => form.firstName = "abcd",1000);
```

Через секунду должно засеттиться новое значение в `firstName`, но этого не происходит. Дебажил, `set firstName()` у `FormComponent` выполняется через секунду, но `set value()` у `InputComponent` не вызывается.

Подскажите, что я упустил? Как правильно сделать такую связь?

Answer (score 0):

React перерисовывает компонент только при изменение `this.state` через вызов `this.setState()`. Поэтому надо вызывать `form.setState({firstName: "abcd"})`. Далее внутри компонента будет определено свойство `this.state.firstName` == "abcd". Его и нужно передавать в дочерний компонент

```
<div>
  <label>First name:</label><br/>
  <InputComponent value={this.state.firstName}/>
</div>
```

Дочерний компонент получит это переменную как `this.props.value` соответственно выводим его так

```
<div className="form__input-wrapper">
  <input value={this.props.value} />
</div>
```

Так должно работать. Хотя не уверен что вызывать `setState` не изнутри класса компонента хорошая идея. Лучше перенести этот таймер в конструктор `FormComponent`